# Mongodb connection failed (Connection refused)

Tags: mongodb

I'm creating a basic web application on OSX for the first time.

I've installed MongoDB and I can use the 'mongo' command from the terminal, but I can't get into the mongodb shell with it.

```
SOE-SOE01492:evnt humadshah$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-07-13T13:29:20.917+0500 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-07-13T13:29:20.917+0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I have absolutely no idea what is causing this. I have never encountered this error on Windows before.

Comment: Could you provide the contents of mongo configuration file?
It should be located at /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in that directory...

Comment: Can you tell me how did you install mongo on your mac? Did you use homebrew?

Comment: I downloaded the compressed file from the MongoDB website and followed the installation instructions for OSX. It involved unpacking the file, placing it in a directory of my choice, and then updating my PATH.

Comment: I would recommend following the instructions on this link:https://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/mac/mongo-mac.html

Comment: It has step-by-step instructions. On a mac installing mongo is as simple as running "brew install mongodb" from the command line.

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I try this code and work for me. Make sure you fully step install mongodb.

```
$ brew services start mongodb
```

then check your connection mongodb

```
$ mongo
```

The result :

```
Server has startup warnings: 
2017-10-01T10:54:13.444+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-10-01T10:54:13.445+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-10-01T10:54:13.445+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-10-01T10:54:13.445+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Comment: execute below command sudo chown -R mongodb /var/lib/mongodb and then sudo service mongod restart

Answer (score 4):

`mongo` command is just a client to connect to mongodb. If mongodb process is not running, `mongo` command fails the connect to mongodb.

Can you try starting mongodb service manually? I do not know how to start it in OSX but in linux it would be;

```
$ sudo service mongodb start
```

or

```
$ sudo systemctl start mongodb
```

For OSX

```
$ cd mongo-db-directory
$ ./bin/mongod
```

Comment: It tells me that 'service' and 'systemctl' are not recognized

Comment: Can you try the updated answer? Keep in mind that you need to try using `mongo` after running `mongod`.